# My code keeps incrementing the number of files it uploads, should only be single file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a jquery dialog form that has this button on it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload()" value="">Upload Photo</button>
```

It uploads a file ok but if you the click the button again it will upload two files this time, another click you get three files and so on.  Below is the js function the button calls:

```
function gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload() {
  $("#gpa_pl_upd_photo").trigger('click');
  $("#gpa_pl_upd_photo").change(function(e) {

    alert('gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload');

    var varPic = $('#gpa_pl_upd_photo')[0].files[0];
    var varExistingPhotoID = $("#gpa_pl_upd_photoid").val();

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', varPic); //this is an object, not a value
    formData.append('existing_pic', varExistingPhotoID);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php/gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload.php",
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {

   /* removed the rest of the code */
```

I added this code the top of the php file to disable it to see whether it was the js causing it or the php code:

```
<?php
  exit;
```

The issue is not being caused by the php code.  I can see in c:\xamppp\tmp that the button is doing the incremental uploading of files.  Can you guys see any reason for this to be happening?

Comment: Every time you click the button you call `$("#gpa_pl_upd_photo").change()`, which adds another event listener. You should do that just once when the page is loaded, not inside the function.

Comment: Thank you !  I'll make that change and report back

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

After Barmar posted their comment I went back and made these modifications which now work perfectly.  Hope this helps someone else.

```
<input style="display:none" type="file" id="gpa_pl_upd_photo" onInput="gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload_two()" name="gpa_pl_upd_photo" value="">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload_one()" value="">Upload Photo</button>

function gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload_one(){
    $("#gpa_pl_upd_photo").show();
    $("#gpa_pl_upd_photo").focus();
    $("#gpa_pl_upd_photo").click();
    $("#gpa_pl_upd_photo").hide();
}

function gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload_two(){ 
    var varPic = $('#gpa_pl_upd_photo')[0].files[0];
    var varExistingPhotoID = $("#gpa_pl_upd_photoid").val();
                
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', varPic);
    formData.append('existing_pic',varExistingPhotoID);

    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "php/gpa_pl_upd_photo_upload.php",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,                   
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data, status, xhr){

    /* removed the rest of the code */
```